# Setting value of jQuery selector is undefined

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to be able to clear the values for some jQuery input objects in a modal dialog for the user.

When the user enters data in the dialog box and either uses the close or submit button and then the next time the user edits another record, the previous value of the input fields are still on the form.

When debugging, the value of the jQuery selector is 'undefined'.

I thought it was because I am using it before the $(document).ready function, but while debugging, I have ensured that this code does not execute until the DOM is loaded.

How can I clear the contents of the input controls for next use by the user?

### Below, is my pertinent HTML

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            if (typeof contentPageLoadOtherDeptsTransfer == "function") contentPageLoadOtherDeptsTransfer();
        });
    </script>

<div class="modal fade" id="btnOtherDeptsTransferEditGrid" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="btnOtherDeptsTransferEditGrid-label" aria-hidden="true">
                                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="btnOtherDeptsTransferEditGrid-label">Edit Other Depts Transfer</h4>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                                <div class='form-group'>
                                                                    <label class="required col-lg-1 control-label" for="txtOtherDeptsTransferStatusComments">No controls in PowerPoint:</label>
                                                                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-1">
                                                                        <textarea id="txtOtherDeptsTransferStatusComments" rows="5" cols="80" class="form-control"></textarea>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="hide-text">
                                                                    <input type="hidden" id="txtOtherDeptsTransferEditGridID" />
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                                            <button type="submit" id="btnOtherDeptsTransferAccept" class="btn btn-success">Accept</button>
                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
</asp:Content>
```

### Here is my pertinent JS:

```
function contentPageLoadOtherDeptsTransfer()
{

    // Clear fields in Dialog box before dialog is shown............................//
    $('#btnOtherDeptsTransferEditGrid').on('show.bs.modal', function ()
    {
        $('txtOtherDeptsTransferStatusComments').val("");
    })
}
```

Comment: Your selector is invalid - missing `#`.  And I don't believe `show.bs.modal` is a valid "event" as per the jQuery documentation:  http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Sparky It's is, but it's a custom event Bootstrap listens, not DOM event.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot the "#" sign....  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('txtOtherDeptsTransferStatusComments').val("");
```

Add a # before 'txt'

**new**

```
$('#txtOtherDeptsTransferStatusComments').val("");
```

Comment: when you have an ID with a name that long...it's gonna happen.  :)